# Changes to make a python code faster and more efficient

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am running the following code to conduct a simulation. I have a dataset of around 100K observations. The simulation does the following:

1. It randomly assign 10 "friends" to each observation
2. Take the average of the variable `normalized_score` of the 10 friends
3. Run a regression where the left hand side variable is the `normalized_score` and the left hand side variable is the average `normalized_score` of the 10 friends
4. Save the coefficient from the regression

I run this simulation 2500 times. It took around 20 days to finish. I tried parallelization and randomization with replacement to make the code more efficient with no luck. I would like to ideally give each observation a 100 random friends, but I would like to make the code faster before doing this. Could you please provide some suggestions on how to make the code faster and more efficient?

Thank you for your help!

Here is the python code I wrote

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyprojroot.here import here
import statsmodels.api as sm
from linearmodels.iv import IV2SLS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import traceback
import seaborn as sns
import random
random.seed(42)  # You can use any number as the seed

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
dir = "path"
data1 = pd.read_csv(dir + 'data1.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv("path")

data = pd.merge(data1, data2, how='right', on='ID', suffixes=('', '_inSchool'))

def calculate_average_score(data, friends_dict):
    average_scores = []
    for key in friends_dict:
        friends = friends_dict[key]['friends']
        
        friends_scores = data[data['ID'].isin(friends)]['normalized_score'].mean()
        
        average_scores.append({
            'ID': key,
            'friends_avg_score': friends_scores
        })
    return pd.DataFrame(average_scores)

def select_friends(data):
    friends_dict = {}
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        friends = data.sample(n=10, replace=False)
        friends_dict[row['ID']] = {
            'friends': friends['ID'].tolist()
        }
    return friends_dict

    coefficients = []


for i in range(2500):
    friends_dict = select_friends(data)
    avg_score_df = calculate_average_score(data, friends_dict)

    data = data.merge(avg_score_df, on='ID', how='left')

    formula = "normalized_score ~ 1 + friends_avg_score"
    ols_model = sm.OLS.from_formula(formula, data=data).fit()
    
    # Extract and store the coefficient of interest (friends_avg_score)
    coefficients.append(ols_model.params['friends_avg_score'])
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: SO is good for debugging code, and at least for `numpy`, suggestions on 'vectorization'.  We can also suggest changes for `pandas`.  But it looks like your code uses added packages like that `statsmodel.api`, which few of us know (any tag for that?),  And your 'no luck' problem(s) is too vague.  Some profiling might help - what at the slow parts, or is it just the shear number of simulations?  CR style of answers might be useful, but study some before posting your question there.